# Transpose rows into columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to transpose rows into columns. There are 2 tables (shown below). Each record in the `product` table matches with `0` or `1` or `2` records in the `product_segment` table. There can be 2 types of products - `HOS` & `AMB`. The requirement is to populate the "segment" values into their corresponding 2 columns (1 for HOS & 1 for AM) in the target, based on this product type.

Populate value for that HOS_segment or AMB_segment in the target based on whichever corresponding `product-type` record exists in the source. If both record-types are present then populate both fields in output Or else populate the one that exists.

Assume the tables as :

Product:

```
product_id | eff_date
12345 | 10/01/2018
75852 | 22/05/2018
33995 | 15/02/2019
```

product_segment:

```
product_id | segment | type
12345 | KA | HOS
12345 | HM | AMB
75852 | GB | HOS
33995 | HD | AMB
```

Expected output:

```
product_id | eff_date | HOS_segment | AMB_segment
12345 | 10/01/2018 | KA | HM
75852 | 22/05/2018 | GB | Null
33995 | 15/02/2019 | Null | HD
```

For `product 12345` both HOS and AMB records exists hence, in the output both the columns get populated with their corresponding segments.
For `product 75852` only the HOS record exists, hence, HOS_segment gets populated but AMB_segment gets Null
And finally just the opposite happens for `product 33995`. AMB_segment gets populated but HOS_segment gets Null

Can anyone please help me solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of using joins and where I would suggest single join with pivot. here is the code snippet have a look.

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df1= spark.createDataFrame([[12345,"10/01/2018"],[75852,"10/01/2018"],[33995,"10/01/2018"]],["product_id","eff_date"])
>>> df1.show()
+----------+----------+                                                         
|product_id|  eff_date|
+----------+----------+
|     12345|10/01/2018|
|     75852|10/01/2018|
|     33995|10/01/2018|
+----------+----------+

>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[12345,"KA","HOS"],[12345,"HM","AMB"],[75852,"GB","HOS"],[33995,"HD","AMB"]],["product_id","Segment","type"])
>>> df2.show()

+----------+-------+----+
|product_id|Segment|type|
+----------+-------+----+
|     12345|     KA| HOS|
|     12345|     HM| AMB|
|     75852|     GB| HOS|
|     33995|     HD| AMB|
+----------+-------+----+

>>> df1.join(df2,df1.product_id ==df2.product_id,"inner").groupBy(df2.product_id,df1.eff_date).pivot("type").agg(F.first(df2.Segment)).show()
+----------+----------+----+----+
|product_id|  eff_date| AMB| HOS|
+----------+----------+----+----+
|     12345|10/01/2018|  HM|  KA|
|     33995|10/01/2018|  HD|null|
|     75852|10/01/2018|null|  GB|
+----------+----------+----+----+
```

> **Spark-sql 2.4+**

```
>>> df1.registerTempTable("df1_temp")
>>> df2.registerTempTable("df2_temp")
>>> spark.sql("select * from(select a.*,b.segment,b.type from df1_temp a inner join df2_temp b on a.product_id =b.product_id) PIVOT( first(segment) for type in ('HOS' HOS_segment,'AMB' AMB_Segment )) " ).show()
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|product_id|  eff_date|HOS_segment|AMB_Segment|
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|     12345|10/01/2018|         KA|         HM|
|     33995|10/01/2018|       null|         HD|
|     75852|10/01/2018|         GB|       null|
+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I hope it will help you. let me know if you have any questions related to same.

Comment: have a look on this https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff - can PIVOT be implemented in SparkSQL instead of pyspark-sql ? what would be the syntax ?

Comment: i tried but can not get it to work. Any help you could offer please ?           
`select * from (
select p.product_id, p.eff_date, first(ps.segment) AS hos_segment, first(ps.segment) AS Amb_segment
from product p
inner join product_segment ps
on p.product_id = ps.product_id
)
PIVOT(first(ps.segment) FOR ps.type IN ('HOS', 'AMB'))`

Comment: updated answer have look and don't forget to Accept and vote up the Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join with a filtered segment table.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

product \
.join(product_segment.where("type = 'HOS'").select("product_id", F.col("segment").alias("HOS_segment")), "product_id", "left_outer") \
.join(product_segment.where("type = 'AMB'").select("product_id", F.col("segment").alias("AMB_segment")), "product_id", "left_outer")
```